# Theorem 2.8 in baby Rudin alternative proof

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

The theorem says that "every infinite subset of a countable set A is countable". In order to prove this Rudin creates a 1-1 mapping of $J= (1,2,3,...)$ onto $E$ which is the subset in question $(E\subset A)$.

But I'm wondering if there is a way to create a bijection like this $f:A \rightarrow E $ to show that $A \sim E$ and since $A \sim J$ then from Definition 2.3 it follows that $E \sim J$.

It was proposed by a friend of mine, saying that we can use the common elements of $A$ and $E$, but I don't really see how to construct such a function. Can somebody come up with the idea or prove that there is no such fuction possible, which is also fine for me. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course that this idea works. But it will ultimately fail, or contain the proof you find in Rudin.

If $f\colon J\to E$ is a bijection, and $g\colon J\to A$ is a bijection, then $f\circ g^{-1}\colon A\to E$ is a bijection. And the same can be said about *any* other set which is countable. You're not married to $A$ or to $J$ in this aspect.

But it is usually unclear how to create a bijection like that directly, and it is much easier to just create a bijection from the natural numbers to $E$. Moreover, it is not true if $A$ is uncountable that every infinite subset is countable (e.g. $A$ itself is not countable!), so you have to use the assumption on $A$. And the only reasonable way of using this assumption is to essentially begin by enumerating $A$ (i.e. fixing $g$ as above), and using that to construct a bijection between $E$ and "some countable set". So might as well use $J$ as most proofs do.